# SQL Server: selecting distinct values per one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was wandering if it's possible to filter select results removing values that partially overlap

For example below, i have thousands of records, but i need the 'week date' value to be unqiue, and in case of duplicates the one with the highest value should remain.

```
emplo   project_id  Value   week_Date    week_ActualStart   week_ActualEnd
A0001   project001  100     2015-12-28   2015-12-28         2016-01-03 
A0001   project001  60      2015-12-28   2016-01-01         2016-01-03
```

So only the first row should remain.

I could really use someone's advice

Comment: `select * from (select Row_Number() Over(partition by week_Date Order by Value desc) ,.. ) a where rn = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
;WITH WeekDateCte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emplno, week_Date ORDER BY Value DESC) RowNo 
    FROM employee
)
SELECT * 
FROM WeekDateCte 
WHERE RowNo = 1
```

For more information about ROW_NUMBER function, check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

**NOTE:** `ROW_NUMBER()` returns `BIGINT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
SELECT emplno, project_id, Value, week_Date,
       week_ActualStart, week_ActualEnd
FROM (
   SELECT emplno, project_id, Value, week_Date,
          week_ActualStart, week_ActualEnd,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emplno, week_Date 
                             ORDER BY Value DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The query picks the row having the greatest `Value` per `emplno, week_Date` slice.